# Scala JUnit assertSame

Tags: scala, junit, equality

In Scala JUnit, how can I assert on memory reference equality? It appears that using:

```
@Test def someTest() = {
  obj1: MyClass = getObject()
  obj2: MyClass = getObject()
  assertSame(obj1, obj2)
}
```

Does *not* compare the memory reference of the two objects but instead calls the `equals()` method of the `MyClass` class.

Comment: This should work. Are you sure it isn't working? What does `assertSame(128, 128)` do?

Comment: It still calls the equals method for the Int class. I want to check the memory reference of the instances, *not* invoke the class `equals()` method.

Comment: How are you confirming this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `assertEq`, take a look at t[he documentation for SUnit's Assert](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.8.0/scala/testing/SUnit$$Assert.html)

```
assertEq(obj1, obj2)
```

Alternatively, you could use something a little more verbose while sticking to JUnit and Scalatest. ([docs](http://doc.scalatest.org/1.3/org/scalatest/junit/AssertionsForJUnit.html))

```
assert(obj1 eq obj2, "Some meaningful message")
```

Comment: The code base I'm editing uses JUnit in Scala instead of SUnit. I guess I can use both in the test suite or try switching over completely to SUnit instead.

Comment: @terminex9 would a simple Scalatest `assert(obj1 eq obj2, "Object references not equal")` work for you?

Comment: Didn't think about that! That appears to work for what I want!

Comment: @terminex9 btw, if you're using `assertSame` from `org.junit.Assert`, it should actually do the trick. How are you verifying that the object references are actually the same/different?